# 32GB RAM aren't running well together but are same

Tags: windows, memory, bios

I got 4x 8GB Ram. Two sets:

- `CMZ16GZ3M2A1600C10` x2
- `CML16GZ3M2A1600C10R` x 2

If I run them separate, everything work fine. System boot up in 4 seconds and everything is smooth in games and windows. By separate I mean 2 dimm modules at once, not all 4.

If I run both together, the system take 30 seconds to boot and I lag in games. CPU is getting used a bit more. My CPU is an Intel i5 2500k. In the data sheet I see 32 GB limitation in RAM and 1333MHz but it not suppose to make this huge difference.

I did try to OC CPU at 4.0GHz with forcing RAM to be `9-9-9-24` and `10-10-10-27` 1600MHz but not change.

If I add my old 2x4 1333 MHz + one set (so 24 GB, running @ 1600 MHz, 16 native and the other 8 GB is OC from 1333 to 1600) everything is fine also.

Any clue ?

Comment: Funny how you can not see they are NOT the same when you even write their different codes.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot combine registered memory and unbuffered memory in the same system.